# Show div as the page scrolls on div height

Tags: jquery, offset

I am trying to animate(show) a **div** as the page scrolls to that div's height(animate according to div's height because *div height* is **variable** since my layout is responsive so as the page gets smaller *div height* changes too...)

Because offset() doesn't see hidden elements, I added a div(#box) to be able to get the height of target ***div***(magicBox).

What I have done so far:

```
$('.magicBox').hide();
var box = $('#box');
var boxPosition = box.offset();
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() <= boxPosition.top) {
   $('.magicBox').show('slow');
}
});
```

It doesn't work! what is wrong here?
http://jsfiddle.net/6hq3V/

I updated it! I am almost there  with scrollTop but it doesn't still appear as the page on #box height..

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == boxPosition.top) {
    $('.magicBox').show('slow');
}
```

`$(document).height()`  was constant and so it couldn't fire anything while  `.scrollTop()` give you the scrollBar position.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hq3V/1

Comment: I've tried that also but magicBox still appears as the page even little bit scrolls not as the page scroll to the #div height 
http://jsfiddle.net/6hq3V/3/

Comment: == boxPosition.top is maybe what you are looking for.

Comment: It didn't work just as What I was trying to do but I think
    if($(window).scrollTop() <= 150) works fine too.. Thnx for help!

Comment: Even if it works , it's probably not the best solution because if for some reasons you'll have to change your layout, you will be forced to change the script as well.